Pressure drop/pressure difference in proportional servo valves and relation to flow rate
In the documentation for servo valves, we often see flow diagrams illustrating the relationship between flow rate and pressure drop (ΔP), as shown in the attached diagram.

I have the following questions:
1- Is there a difference between the pressure drop caused by turbulence and friction when the flow passes through a valve and the pressure difference required to drive flow from the inlet to the outlet of the valve? Are these concepts the same, and are they calculated similarly?
2- If these concepts are not the same, which one is represented in the flow diagrams for these valves? Do the diagrams indicate the flow rate corresponding to a given pressure difference between the inlet and outlet of the valve, or do they show the pressure drop due to friction expected at a specific flow rate?
Thank you in advance for your clarification.

The diagrams I believe show the pressure difference between the inlet and outlet for a given flow rate. As far as I am aware there is no method apart maybe from CFD in which you can breakdown the pressure drop into its turbulence and friction components. So to answer your first question the pressure drop from the inlet to the outlet is caused by phenomena such as wall friction and turbulence.
